# How to refer external jar route from Camel context file

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I have project A which has below simple route **logrouteTest.xml**

```
    <routeContext id="CommonLogRoutes" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="logRoute">
            <from id="_NSDL_PAN" uri="seda:MyLogRoute"/>
            <convertBodyTo id="_convertBodyTo1" type="java.lang.String"/>
            <log message="my received body : ${body}"/>            
        </route>
  </routeContext>
```

I composed this project into JAR.
In my project B I have imported the above jar and trying to refer the Project A route like this

```
<import resource="classpath:com/tcl/Testjar/logrouteTest.xml"/>
```

**Error**
I am getting the below error
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/tcl/Testjar/logrouteTest.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Is there any way to refer the external project camel route from current project route without deploying project A.

**Note** :  I am looking for option to use Project A as ESB library

Comment: This is relatively easy to do with the Java DSL I am not sure if this is possible from a XML based route as I have migrated to Java DSL a few years ago.

Comment: <!-- Add this in depency -->
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.myrepo.logger</groupId>
 <artifactId>logger-module</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

<!-- add the dependency project in profile section -->
<profiles>
 <profile>
  <id>jdk9+-build</id>
  <activation>
   <jdk>[9,)</jdk>
  </activation>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.myrepo.logger</groupId>
    <artifactId>logger-module</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
 </profile>
</profiles>

Comment: My dependencies are good, I am using springboot with multimodule and camel xml files are in a camel-module. Locally it works but not when deployed to test server. Anyway thanks..